# Navigate to root without back in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have some problems using angular navigation in ionic 4
in app.component.ts i can check storage to navigate to Login page or Home page if the user is logged in or not as example :

The user is logged in so he will go direct to home page (http://localhost:8100/home) if I tabbed the back button the navigation changes to (http://localhost:8100)

My Code :

```
public ngOnInit() {
 if ("settingsService" in localStorage) {
  let SettingsData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settingsService'))
  if ((SettingsData["username"] != null || SettingsData["username"] != "") && (SettingsData["password"] != null || SettingsData["password"] != "")) {
    if (SettingsData["currentLanguage"] == 1025) {
      this.setLang('ar');
    } else {
      this.setLang('en');
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
} else {
  this.setLang('en');
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/shared/login');
}
}
```

My App Pages :

```
  public appPages = [
{ title: 'Home', url: '/home', icon: 'home' },
{ title: 'Reports', url: '/shared/menu', icon: 'planet' }]
```

Another example in side menu if the Home page is opened then the Reports tabbed I can go back from Reports to Home (Both are Parents) by tabbing back button

[image]

How can i prevent this?

Comment: HI Mohammad. If you can add more details and specifically relevant code to your question it will help people to provide better answers. SO has a guide on crafting questions here: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need to remove previous page from navigation stack in ionic 4